# UITableViewCell - drag whole row to move?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use a `UITableViewController` and allow the user to reorganize my data by dragging the rows.  This is working fine, except that the user has to tap on the relatively small `UITableViewCellReorderControl` on the right quarter of the cell to drag the row.

Here's an example:

[image: dragging works]

As far as I can tell there's no way to get ahold of the `UITableViewCellReorderControl` or access its size or behavior through the `UITableViewDelegate`.  Is there a way to customize drag behavior so that you can drag anywhere on the cell to move it up or down?

Comment: This is not simple if you want to implement custom drag/drop reorder feature because you need to get screenshot of moving cell and follow touch gesture moving and reorder cell. Also you need to consider scrolling if user drag to the top or to the bottom.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it on the whole cell, however you will have to implement everything manually. It includes creating a gesture recognizer (probably `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on your tableView and then calling `beginInteractiveMovementForItem`, `updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition`, etc... based on the state of your recognizer. You will also have to manually set the cell position and, as Ryan mentioned, implement the scroll for drag to the top or bottom of the tableView. I am sure there are many tutorials to implement this.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/adamshin/SwiftReorder) of a custom implementation of the drag and drop functionality if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

just expand the reorderControl to the size of cell.

```
extension UITableViewCell {
  var reoderControl: UIView? {
      for view in self.subviews {
          if view.description.contains("UITableViewCellReorderControl") {
              return view
          }
      }
      return nil
  }
}
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
     override func layoutSubviews() {
         super.layoutSubviews()
         reoderControl?.frame = bounds
     }
}
```